# how to create a java script with confirmation message which should refresh page after running form script?

Tags: javascript, html, sql, oracle, plsql

I would like a javascript pop up to show the input of the user with a question asking if they are sure. But the javascript should run after the user has clicked yes or ok button. it should then refresh the page. i have done something similar, however my javascript pops up after i manually refresh the page and it then shows the pop up message twice. my form is basically updating a column on a table.

-- form --

```
HTP.FORMOPEN ('BANINST1.HWZKLISS.P_GRE_ID','post');
HTP.FORMHIDDEN ('bannerid',stuid);
htp.p ('<input type="text" method="post" name="newid" id="newid" placeholder="Enter New ID Here..." maxlength="20" 
                        autocomplete="off">');                    
HTP.P ('<input type="submit" value="Update ID" onClick="reloadpage();">');
HTP.FORMCLOSE;
```

-- javascript --

```
   htp.p ('<script type="text/javascript"');
   htp.p ('function reloadpage()
                        {
                        var returnURL = "P_LOCAL_ID_SEARCH" + Math.random() * 100;
                        setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location=returnURL; 
                        }, 50 );
                        }'
                        );

   htp.p('</script>');
```

-- update script --

```
  IF newid IS NOT NULL THEN       
                UPDATE GENERAL.GORADID
                    SET GORADID_ADDITIONAL_ID = newid                  
                        WHERE GORADID_PIDM = (SELECT SPRIDEN_PIDM
                                                FROM SPRIDEN
                                                WHERE SPRIDEN_ID = bannerid 
                                                AND SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND IS NULL);

    htp.p ('<script type="text/javascript">');
    htp.p (' alert("Student Local ID has now been updated to:   '||newid||'")');
    htp.p ('</script>');

    COMMIT;
    END IF;
```

Comment: @user7294900 Because i'm working on Toad for Oracle ?

Comment: @user7294900 - the OP is using `htp.p` which is part of [OracleAS PL/SQL Web Toolkit](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b15896/pshtp.htm). So clearly Oracle is at least partly relevant to question.